# FGLRX driver causing login-loop Radeon HD 6470m Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, fglrx, amd-graphics

I wanted to install the fglrx driver because the system runs hot and I thought the fglrx driver could help with that.

I've been looking for a very long time around for answers. But no one seems to have the same situation as me.

I simply tried to install a fglrx driver from the "*additional drivers*" in settings. The installation runs as it should. But then when rebooting it does not automatically login. Trying to log in takes me back to lightdm same with guest.

So from there I did <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f1</kbd> and I manually purged the driver `sudo apt-get --purge remove fglrx` and updated packages after that. `sudo apt-get update` This makes me go back to the open source driver and after rebooting everything is back to normal, I can login. I do have tried to install the fglrx driver again with the Terminal

```
sudo apt-get fglrx
```

but that doesn't help.

If I have to do something very advanced I can consider living with the open source driver.

All help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I've upgraded to 16.04. And since the fglrx options in "Additional Drivers" are gone I guess they are trying to tell me that the Radeon HD 6470m is incompatible with the fglrx drivers given out and that must be the answer to the login loop.

Over time the open source drivers are getting better and I don't feel like I need the fglrx drivers anymore.

Comment: fglrx was discontinued and isn't included in newer Ubuntu releases.